# Как растянуть блок с фото

Tags: html, css

Как сделать чтобы фотографии располагались без отступов по краям страницы, по всей ширине экрана, на всех разрешениях.
Можно ссылку на статью, где это разбирается. В гугле не нашел ничего подходящего.    [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Пример на jsbin](https://jsbin.com/dowesu/edit?html,css,output)

```css
.row {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bit-4 {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="bit-4">
        <img src="http://orig08.deviantart.net/de1b/f/2010/331/1/b/darth_vader_icon_128x128_by_geo_almighty-d33pmwn.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="bit-4">
        <img src="http://orig08.deviantart.net/de1b/f/2010/331/1/b/darth_vader_icon_128x128_by_geo_almighty-d33pmwn.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="bit-4">
        <img src="http://orig08.deviantart.net/de1b/f/2010/331/1/b/darth_vader_icon_128x128_by_geo_almighty-d33pmwn.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="bit-4">
        <img src="http://orig08.deviantart.net/de1b/f/2010/331/1/b/darth_vader_icon_128x128_by_geo_almighty-d33pmwn.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
      <div class="bit-4">
        <img src="http://orig08.deviantart.net/de1b/f/2010/331/1/b/darth_vader_icon_128x128_by_geo_almighty-d33pmwn.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="bit-4">
        <img src="http://orig08.deviantart.net/de1b/f/2010/331/1/b/darth_vader_icon_128x128_by_geo_almighty-d33pmwn.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="bit-4">
        <img src="http://orig08.deviantart.net/de1b/f/2010/331/1/b/darth_vader_icon_128x128_by_geo_almighty-d33pmwn.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="bit-4">
        <img src="http://orig08.deviantart.net/de1b/f/2010/331/1/b/darth_vader_icon_128x128_by_geo_almighty-d33pmwn.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Это если, чтобы

> на всех разрешениях

А если для разных устройств по разному, то применяются media запросы. Подробнее об адаптивной верстке можно узнать в [htmlbook](https://webref.ru/layout/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design)

Comment: Немного подправил код для своих целей. Но это помогло! Здоровья тебе :D

Answer (score 2):

```
img{
padding:0;
margin:0;
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: на jsfiddle дай пример

Comment: пикчи на фотохостинг залей,а то они битые у тя

Comment: Все, залил все.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ojppe60z/9/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/qkL28L58/